How to track data from scorm
I need to have statistics on how many times a scroll or slide has been opened.
The problem is that the scorm file will be uploaded to an LMS platform that isn't mine and I have no idea what the url is.
Is there a way to insert some kind of code or image or function, that I can trace to see this data?
To create the scorm I use articulate.
nothing, I was looking at some guide with Google analytics, but I always have to put the website, which I don't know what it is. or rather I don't know which domain will be chosen.
